# swift mapkit show route and calculate distance

Tags: swift, macos, mapkit

i working with swift 4 for osx.
i would like to realize the following situation:

- Show a Map (this works)
- Show sourceLocation (this works)
- Show targetLocation (this works)
- get the distance between sourceLocation and targetLocation (this works)

This is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {

    let myLocation = myMap.userLocation.coordinate
    myMap.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myLocation, 500, 500), animated: true)

       let address = "XXX"
       let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
       geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
       guard let placemarks = placemarks, let targetLocation = placemarks.first?.location
       else {
          return
       }

       let sourceLocation = CLLocation(latitude: myLocation.latitude, longitude: myLocation.longitude)
       var distance = sourceLocation .distance(from: targetLocation)


       let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
       annotation.coordinate = targetLocation.coordinate
       self.myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)


       // Distance in km between sourceLocation and targetLocation
       print(distance.rounded()/1000, " km")
      }              
    }
```

Now my problems :)

- every time when i start my app and the map will shown, the authentication request for the userlocation will appear. is there a way to save the authentication answer of the user, so that the request will not comes every time?
- is there an way to show possible routes for user- to targetLocation.and if the user select an route, that this distance will save into the var distance?

Comment: Use the delegate methods for the first one.

Comment: and which delegate methods will "save" the authentication answer of the user?